# Image is not showing in browser?

Tags: html, image, jsp

```
<body style="background-color: paleturquoise">
    <h2 style="color: red">Duke's soccer League: Home Page<br/></h2>
    <ul style="list-style-type: circle">
        <li style="font-size: larger"><a href="league_list.in">All Leagues list</a></li>
        <li style="font-size: larger">Register for a League (TBA)<br/><br/></li>
    </ul>
    <h2 style="color: red">League Administrator</h2>
    <ul style="list-style-type: square">
        <li style="font-size: larger"><a href="add_league.in">Add a new League (TBA)</a></li>

        <img  src="C:\Users\VIRK\Desktop\66.jpg" width="400" height="400" ></img>

</ul>
</body>
```

I am currently practice with JSP and I try this html code to make a web page on NetBeans IDE 7.0 but when I'm build and run the page no error in code but the image is not showing in the browser.

**Edited:**

[image]

Here I have given the screenshot of the NetBeans IDE where you can see the image is existing in Web-INF folder and the index.jsp page too and I tried with `"/"` before the image name but it won't work. The exact path of my project is C:\Users\VIRK\Documents\NetBeansProjects\practiceJSP .

```
<img  src="/66.jpg" width="400" height="400" ></img>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Css background image url problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401865/css-background-image-url-problem)

Comment: The duplicate deals with background images, but the solution is exactly the same.

Comment: Add `file://` before the image to let the browser know it's local file.

Comment: i tried with this but its not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to show image on JSP Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061168/how-to-show-image-on-jsp-page)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I find out the way how to set the image path just remove the `"/"` before the destination folder as `"images/66.jpg"` not `"/images/66.jpg"` And its working fine for me.

Comment: This was a good catch. I was also confused because there was no compile error.

Comment: This forward slash is always the best for crossplatform use because it doesn't get misinterpreted with the escape sequence back slash.

Answer (score 2):

You put inside img tag **physical** path you your image. Instead of that you should put **virtual** path (according to root of web application) to your image. This value depends on location of your image and your html page.

for example if you have:

```
/yourDir
-page.html
-66.jpg
```

in your page.html it should be something like that:

```
<img  src="66.jpg" width="400" height="400" ></img>
```

second scenario:

```
/images
-66.jpg
/html
page.html
```

So your img should look like:

```
<img  src="../images/66.jpg" width="400" height="400" ></img>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your path should be like this : "http://websitedomain//folderpath/66.jpg">

```
<img  src="http://websitedomain/folderpath/66.jpg" width="400" height="400" ></img>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where you're running the site from on your computer, but you have an absolute file path to your C drive:  C:\Users\VIRK\Desktop\66.jpg

Try this instead:

```
<img  src="[PATH_RELATIVE_TO_ROOT]/66.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
```

**UPDATE:**

I don't know what your `$PROJECTHOME` is set to.  But say for example your site files are located at C:\Users\VIRK\MyWebsite.  And let's say your images are in an 'images' folder within your main site, like so:  C:\Users\VIRK\MyWebsite\images.

Then in your HTML you can simply reference the image within the images folder relative to the site, like so:

```
<img  src="images/66.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
```

Or, assuming you're hosting at the root of localhost and not within another virtual directory, you can do this (note the slash in the beginning):

```
<img  src="/images/66.jpg" width="400" height="400" />
```

Comment: how to set the path with index.jsp in Netbeans i m confused with this because m new with this help will highly appericiate. thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need to read up a bit on NetBeans and your project setup.

Comment: @Kon I find out the way how to set the image path just remove the "/" before the destination folder as "images/66.jpg" not "/images/66.jpg" and thanks for offering help.........If you think its right then edit your answer and re-post it.

Answer (score 0):

all you need to do is right click on the jsp page in the browser, which might look like "localhost:8080/images.jpg, copy this and paste it where the image is getting generated

Answer (score 0):

I had same kind of problem in Netbeans.

I updated the image location in the project and when I executed the jsp file, the image was not loaded in the page.

Then I clean and Built the project in Netbeans. Then it worked fine.

Though you need to check the image actually exists or not using the image URL in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the images would not show and it wasn't the relative path. I even hard coded the actual path and the image still did not show. I had changed my webserver to run on port 8080 and neither

```
<img src="c:/public/images/<?php echo $image->filename; ?>" width="100" />
<img src="c:/public/images/mypic.jpg" width="100" />
```

would not work.

```
<img src="../../images/<?php echo $photo->filename; ?>" width="100" />
```

Did not work either. This did work :

```
<img src="http://localhost:8080/public/images/<?php echo $image->filename; ?>" width="100" />
```

Answer (score 0):

do not place *jsp or *html in root folder of webapp and images you want to display in same root folder browser cannot acess the image in WEB-INF folder

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar problem and tried all of the above but nothing worked.
And then I noticed that the image was loading fine for one file and not for another. The reason was: My image was named image.jpg and a page named about.html could not load it while login.html could. This was because image.jpg was below about and above login. So I guess login.html could refer to the image and about.html couldn't find it. 
I renamed about.html to zabout.html and re-renamed it back. Worked. 
Same may be the case for images enclosed in folders.

Answer (score 0):

the easy way to do it to place the image in Web Content and then right click on it and then open it by your eclipse or net beans web Browser it will show the page where you can see the URL which is the exact path then copy the URL and place it on src=" paste URL " ;

Answer (score 0):

If we are using asp.net "FileUpload" control and want to preview image before upload we can use below code.

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" Style="border: none;" onchange="showpreview(this);" />
<img id="previewImage" src="C:\fakepath\natureImage.jpg">


<script>
    function showpreview(Imagepath) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("#previewImage").attr("src", e.target.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(Imagepath.files[0]);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another random reason for why your images might not show up is because of something called `base href="http://..."` this can make it so that the `images` file doesn't work the way it should. Delete that line and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import your image from the image folder.
`import name_of_image from '../imageFolder/name_of_image.jpg';`

`<img src={name_of_image} alt=''>`

Please refer here.
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files -

Answer (score 0):

The folder names in the path should not contain the space

write fullstack /asset/image.jpg instead of full stack/asset/image.jpg

Comment: This answer brings nothing useable for the others