# how to show image on JSP Page

Tags: java, image, jsp

Here i am new to spring so i have following problems,

I have to show a image on my Home Page of jsp.

I have used img in jsp as,

```
<img src="WebContent/images/SSAgroLOGO.gif" />
```

My Directory Structure is as,

- My App

  - WebContent

    - images

      - **SSAgroLOGO.gif**
    - WEB-INF

      - jsp

        - **HomePage.jsp**

It not showing the image on Page...

So Please Help me,

Thanks in advance...

Comment: you do not need `WebContent/`.  images/SSAgroLOGO.gif should be fine

Comment: No!!!Sir it's not working ....Should i add something in spring-servlet.xml or in web.xml...Please help me!!!

Comment: I have also tried as <img src="images/SSAgroLOGO.gif" alt="SSAgroLOGO" height="42" width="42"/> But not Done...

Comment: check to make sure that the file is deployed to your web server and that the case is correct

Comment: I am using Eclipse for developing and Apache Tomcat 7.......is that ok....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this -

```
<img src="images/SSAgroLOGO.gif" />
```

`WebContent` would be working directory for web-apps. A sample war folder structure visualization -

[image]

and in addition to set other attributes(ex. alt, hieght and others) - [Check Here](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_img.asp)

Comment: This could be a comment rather . please clearly explain about the directory listings also

Comment: yap, my clarification added

Comment: No!!!Sir it's not working ....Should i add something in spring-servlet.xml or in web.xml...Please help me!!!

Comment: I have also tried as <img src="images/SSAgroLOGO.gif" alt="SSAgroLOGO" height="42" width="42"/> But not Done...

Comment: It should work as you follows the folder structure, I really cann't see error exactly while loading the image