# why isn't my image showing up in html?

Tags: html

I'm trying to add an image to my html page. It should be fairly simple. However, the image refuses to show up.

here is the html

```html
        <img src="/images/eiffel.jpg" alt="eiffel">
```

In safari all i get is a question mark. In chrome it is just an icon with the alt. That is the directory where the image is and my IDE autocompletes the photo name so I know i'm in the right place. So why isn't it showing up??

Comment: Remove the first slash

Comment: the path for your image is probably wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image is not showing in browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402600/image-is-not-showing-in-browser)

Comment: removing the slash did not work

Comment: https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-path-absolute-relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add 2 dots behind it will work, if your images folder is in the an upper folder referring to  your webpage.

`<img src="../images/eiffel.jpg" alt="eiffel">`

Comment: it goes like this... home folder contains images folder and the folder which contains my webpage

Comment: In this case, add 2 dots.

Comment: huzzah! you sir, are a saint and a scholar

Comment: your welcome

a correct answer mark might be nice ;)

Answer (score 1):

The leading slash in your `src` URL makes the path relative to the root of your website, it is an **absolute** path.

*Without* the slash, this path becomes **relative** to the HTML document's location.  If this document is not at the website root (eg: `www.example.com/index.html`) then it will not point to the same location as the first example.

For example, if your page URL is `www.example.com/mysite/content/index.html` then the two variations will be interpreted as follows:

```
src="images/eiffel.jpg"       -->  www.example.com/mysite/content/images/eiffel.jpg
src="/images/eiffel.jpg"      -->  www.example.com/images/eiffel.jpg
```

Using dots as mentioned by other answers would produce subtly different results:

```
src="./images/eiffel.jpg"     -->  www.example.com/mysite/content/images/eiffel.jpg
src="../images/eiffel.jpg"    -->  www.example.com/mysite/images/eiffel.jpg
src="../../images/eiffel.jpg" -->  www.example.com/images/eiffel.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the url of the page where the image should show? Remember that by using the slash you are calling base url. Maybe you could use full url or remove the slash at the beginning.

Also you can try previous answer of adding a "." before the slash.

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is the url of the page where you are trying to show the image? are you using sef urls?

Comment: the url is localhost:3000/website/q4/index.htm

Comment: And what is your folder structure? ../website/q4/images/eiffel.jpg? or ../website/images/eiffel.jpg?

Comment: it is website/images/eiffel.jpg... I just needed to add 2 dots instead of one

Answer (score 0):

Check the below Steps which will help you on image rendering issues.

1. Right Click and Choose `Inspect Element`
2. Click Network Tab Search for your Filename
3. Double click your image file name.
4. It will open in your Safari browser.
5. Verify your image absolute path.

You can follow the same trick for every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this because in my code i added the code like this and it worked.
My code is 
img src="C:\Users\User\Desktop\HTML Programs\Proj\bgimg4.jpg"

```
 You can use img src="\images\eiffel.jpg" alt="eiffel" use Markdown in here.
Please keep the above one in angular braces.
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use LOWER CASE for entire path in code.

Change all uppercase when you copy it over to lowercase.

Comment: There are still case-sensitive browsers, web-servers and urls out there. So that may will cause more issues. I would more take care on a "leading-slash" or use base_url to enforce get absolute urls, if the recommended relative urls do not work. See [w3schools - img tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_img_src.asp)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).