# Image not showing up in html live site

Tags: html, css

I have got a site i am busy creating but when i upload my site live, the one image does not show. Here is the code

```
<div id="adbox">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <img src="images/family-large.jpg" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
                <div class="detail">
                    <h1>Implementing Strategic and Effective Legal Solutions</h1>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

> and the css is as follows

```
    .clearfix {
    width: 960px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear:both;
        content:"";
        display:block;
        line-height:0;
        height:100%;
    }
```

[This is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5SpR.jpg)
[What it suppose to show](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a0In4.png)

Comment: It's most likely to be a path issue. Try '/images/family-large.jpg' and inspect the image path in Firebug (or similar)

Comment: send the url of page where image is not loading

Comment: I think `src` should be `../images/family-large.jpg`

Comment: Check image path or for testing purpose put absolute image path in tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Image is not showing in browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6402600/image-is-not-showing-in-browser)

Answer (score 0):

Your path to your image is incorrect. You can easily test this by loading in an image you know will work. Lorem Flickr is great for testing this:

```css
.clearfix {
width: 960px;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:block;
    line-height:0;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="adbox">
  <div class="clearfix">
    <img src="http://www.loremflickr.com/382/594" alt="Img" height="382" width="594">
    <div class="detail">
      <h1>Implementing Strategic and Effective Legal Solutions</h1>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```