# To access image from C directory and display in a panel

Tags: asp.net

In the below code i am trying to display image inside a panel.But my image cannot access the image from C directory and place inside panel.Pls any one me to solve the issue

```
 docimg.ImageUrl = @"C:\Search\Seardoc\Documents\Desert.jpeg";
  imgPnl.BackImageUrl = docimg.ImageUrl;

 <asp:Panel ID="imgPnl" runat="server">
        <asp:Image ID="docimg" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px"  /></asp:Panel>
```

Comment: So you need to display it from client machine or server side to client browser?

Comment: And for your information you need to provide URL and not physical path.

Comment: @ Chirag Vidani the image is in client machine to client browser

Answer (score 0):

use file:/// before the image name

`@"file:\\\C:\Search\Seardoc\Documents\Desert.jpeg";`

Example

[CSS background image URL failing to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401865/css-background-image-url-problem)

Comment: @user3580909 right click on that file and open in web browser copy path from there and use in your image src.

Comment: where do you want to display that file on you local machine or some where else.