# Cant link image from CSS

Tags: hyperlink, navigation, navbar, nav

Trying to get a logo onto a website. Eventually use it as a link to the main page. But it wont even show up when I use css. It does link when I use HTML So i know its not the image. CSS is in its own folder, and Image is in its own folder. So I dont think i have the url incorrect.

CSS

```
.logo {

    background-image: url(../images/logo.png);
    display:block;
    margin: 0px auto;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;
    border: none;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px; 
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

    <div class="logo">

    </div>  

</body>
```

Feel like Ive tried everything.

Comment: Because it's a local file. Locally you need to say `file:///imagePath` (assuming this is on your computer). Anyways this is a duplicate, [more information here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401865/css-background-image-url-failing-to-load).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HERE IS THE ANSWER

css

.logo {

```
background: url(../images/logo.png) ;
background-size: 200px 200px;
width: 200px;
height:200px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try changing background-image to background and adding quotation marks.

```
.logo{ 
 background: url('../images/logo.png');
```