# show local image which not in my project in MVC as background image

Tags: css, background-image

I'm using angularJs to show background image of a div, but when I put the full Path it cant detect the image path.
but anyway, the actual problem is to put local image path as a background image Url.

this is the code:

```
style="background-image: url(C:\\PICTURES\\IMG_8320.jpg);"
```

how can I use a local path as a background image ?

Comment: The `url` in `background-image` should be a web link to your image, either relative or fullpath. Your user's browser will not know where your web server's `C:\pictures\` is.

Comment: @FrankFajardo she's probably testing her website locally before she puts it live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to prefix it by file://

like in your css

```
background-image:url("file:///C:/PICTURES/IMG_8320.jpg");
```

or in style tags

```
<style>
#imgDiv{background-image:url("file:///C:/PICTURES/IMG_8320.jpg");}
</style>
```

Comment: @Eliad ha! i knew i was right check it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401865/css-background-image-url-failing-to-load

Comment: still didn't work it, but you deserve it for your time and Determination. i will mark it as an answer