# background image doesn't work

Tags: css

this is the hmtl of the page and i m not seeing where s the error and the img doesn't show in notepad++.thanyou to answer me

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
    </html>
   /* this line doesn't show the img*/
    body {
       background-image: url("‪C:\Users\zineelabidine\Desktop\fayss.jpg");
       }
```

Comment: Do not use path like `C:\Users\zineelabidine\Desktop\fayss.jpg`. Use a relative path to your server-root.

Comment: If you want to test the image just upload it to a site like imgur and grab the link. Then update your css with the new url.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS background image URL failing to load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401865/css-background-image-url-failing-to-load)

Answer (score 0):

For an img tag, you don't use a fixed path l‪ike ‪C:\Users\zineelabidine\Desktop\fayss.jpg. Use a relative path like url('fayss.jpg'). (That path was assuming that the image and the html file are in the same folder)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your Image and html file in same folder and use this code, Hope it helps you:

```
body {
   background-image: url("fayss.jpg");
   }
```