# Why is css url() function mangling my path?

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, url, electron

In my react app I'm using setting the style of a div to

```
{ backgroundImage: "url(file://f:/images/0/22.jpg)" }
```

but it throws a ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error with a very strange url such as

```
file:///F:/images%EF%BF%BD%22.jpg.
```

Ordinary relative paths to images without file:// work fine and if I copy the path, printed from console, into the inspector it works fine too.

I can't figure out when this transformation happens but prints of the url I'm using in my react component are fine.

Comment: Have you tried it with three slashes after the colon? `file:///f:/images/0/22.jpg`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401865/css-background-image-url-failing-to-load

Comment: Indeed yes, I believe I changed it to two while just trying random things to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the problem was my original url. I didn't notice but the url i was using had backslashes instead of forward slashes.

Using a replace to replace the backslashes with forward slashes has fixed it.

Moral of the story: If you urls look crazy check your slashes.